# What arguments should I pass to l() so that the generated link would open a new popup window?

Tags: 6

I have made my custom module in Drupal. I have a link that should open a popup window.

What arguments should I pass to `l()` so that the generated link would open a new popup window?

Comment: I just only want that my above link should be open in a pop up window

Answer (score 2):

The link formatter function [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) takes 3 arguments:

```
l($text, $path, array $options = array());
```

The $options array specifies the parameters to be passed to the link. One of them is `$options['attributes']` which is itself an array and is used to specify the attributes of the anchor tag.

Use something like:

```
$options['attributes'] = array( 'target' => '_blank' );
```

when you are assembling the parameters to pass. This will open the link in a new window., which is the closest you can get with HTML.

For a real pop-up, you will have to add javascript to do the job, and adding something like:

```
$options['attributes'] = array( 'class' => 'popup' );
```

will give the javascript a target to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [External Link](https://drupal.org/project/extlink) module? AFAICT there's no parameter for `l()` or even for `url()` that specifies a new window, but External Link provides additional behaviors that can be configured for external links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many widget as [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Lightbox](https://drupal.org/node/252260)

In this case you need to add the attribute to the array

```
l(t('Link text'), 'open popup', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('YOUR-CLASS'))));
```

But you can add all the attribute you want, like target so:

```
l(t('Link text'), 'open popup', array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank', 'class' => array ('your classes'), 'another_attr' => 'attr_val'));
```